# Core Data: NSManagedObjects stored in array turn into nil when scrolling in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have some NSManagedObjects that I am retrieving and storing in an array for populating a table view.  When the view first loads, all of the data is there, but when I scroll the NSManagedObjects in the array turn to nil.

I fetch like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tracks" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    NSLog(@"An Error! %@",error);
}

mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchedObjects];
```

My NSManagedObject subclass is named "Tracks".  When the view loads, I can assign a Tracks object from mutArray, but when I scroll the Tracks object is always nil. Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TracksCell";

    TracksCell *cell = (TracksCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TracksCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Tracks *track = [mutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = track.name;
    cell.addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",track.city,track.state];

    return cell;

}
```

So just to be clear, this works when the table first loads.  But if I scroll down then back up the Tracks object on the first row is nil.  Also any rows that haven't been loaded (below the view) are nil when I scroll down.

What am I missing here?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after the initial load - do you still have data in `mutArray`?

Comment: You are missing a perfect use case for a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Why is the array mutable? Are you deliberately removing items from it elsewhere?

Comment: @JanGreve can you explain how I should be using NSFetchedResultsController in this case?  but yes the array is mutable for a reason, I have a search bar and some logic for clicking a favorite button on each cell.  All that code is commented out for now though until I can get the cells actually populating with the info from Core Data

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html

Comment: @JanGreve got it... thats a pretty critical thing to know if you are going to use Core Data.. Thanks!

Comment: That's why it's in the programming guide for core data ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @JanGreve posting the documentation in the comments, heres the answer for anyone needing some help setting up `NSFetchedResultsController`.

**in your .h file:**

add `<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>`

and add property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

**in your .m file:**

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
```

viewDidLoad:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error! %@",error);
    abort();
}
```

add this method to populate your fetchedResultsController:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched Results Controller section
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tracks" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

then in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` get your populate your NSManagedObject subclass like this:

```
Tracks *track = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```